# How to save indices and values from Matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3x3 Matrix and want to save the indices and values into a new 9x3 matrix. For example `A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9]` so that I will get a matrix `x = [1 1 1; 1 2 2; 1 3 3; 2 1 4; 2 2 5; ...]` With my code I only be able to store the last values `x = [3 3 9]`.

```
A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9]; 
x=[];
 for i = 1:size(A)
   for j = 1:size(A)
      x =[i j A(i,j)]
   end
 end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to iterate `x`.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Vectorized approach

Here's one way to do it that avoids loops:

```
A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9];
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,2)); % row and column indices
vv = A.'; % values. Transpose because column changes first in the result, then row
x = [jj(:) ii(:) vv(:)]; % result
```

### Using your code

You're only missing concatenation with previous `x`:

```
A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9];
x = [];
for i = 1:size(A)
  for j = 1:size(A)
    x = [x; i j A(i,j)]; % concatenate new row to previous x
  end
end
```

Two additional suggestions:

- Don't use `i` and `j` as [variable names](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html), because that shadows the imaginary unit.
- [Preallocate](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) `x` instead of having it grow in each iteration, to increase speed.

The modified code is:

```
A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9];
x = NaN(numel(A),3); % preallocate
n = 0;
for ii = 1:size(A)
  for jj = 1:size(A)
    n = n + 1; % update row counter
    x(n,:) = [ii jj A(ii,jj)]; % fill row n
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a solution that works much faster. Here is the code:

```
% Generate subscripts from linear index
[i, j] = ind2sub(size(A),1:numel(A));

% Just concatenate subscripts and values
x = [i' j' A(:)];
```

Try it out and let me know ;)